# Does a scrub operation remove expired columns?

Tags: cassandra

I'm aware that nodetool scrub removed tombstones that are past gc_grace seconds.

I'm curious: does a nodetool scrub also remove or insert a tombstone when it encounters data that has an expired TTL? If so, doing a scrub seems like a more efficient way to remove expired data when compared to a major compaction.

Comment: The normal way to handle cleaning of tombstones is to let minor compactions do it automatically for you (for versions of cassandra > 0.6.8). Are you running with minor compactions disabled?

Comment: I don't have minor compactions disabled, but I feel like it's easy to end up in a situation where I have one large SSTable where all the data is expired. Doing a periodic major compaction (or scrub?) is a way to ensure that the old data is regularly removed